# Access query criteria where field contains no numbers

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I want to make a query criteria that not alike %Any Number% this includes numerical values as well as any string containing a number. Right now i am using this as my expression. it works, but I would like to simplify my code.

```
SELECT Distinct tblProductionTime.production_order_number
FROM tblProductionTime
GROUP BY tblProductionTime.production_order_number
HAVING (((tblProductionTime.production_order_number) Not ALike "%0%" And
(tblProductionTime.production_order_number) Not ALike "%1%" And
(tblProductionTime.production_order_number) Not ALike "%2%" And
(tblProductionTime.production_order_number) Not ALike "%3%" And
(tblProductionTime.production_order_number) Not ALike "%4%" And
(tblProductionTime.production_order_number) Not ALike "%5%" And
(tblProductionTime.production_order_number) Not ALike "%6%" And
(tblProductionTime.production_order_number) Not ALike "%7%" And
(tblProductionTime.production_order_number) Not ALike "%8%" And
(tblProductionTime.production_order_number) Not ALike "%9%"));
```

Comment: You are doing things in a very complicated way here. GROUP BY should be used in combination with aggregate functions (SUM, MAX, COUNT etc). SELECT DISTINCT is enough to remove duplicates. HAVING clause is (normally) used for aggregate functions only, put all your conditions in the WHERE clause instead.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
Not ALike "%[0-9]%"
```

This will trap a field / column that contains any numeric value between 0 and 9 anywhere.